# VB.NET Winforms: Overlay two transparent images

Tags: vb.net, winforms, image

I am attempting to overlay two transparent images within a winform, but it keeps rendering the form's background image behind the top transparent image, as opposed to the second image...

My basic set up is I have two panels and in each panel is a picturebox. Each image in the picture boxes have some transparent areas. I've set the BackColor of the panels to color.transparent.

When I make one panel overlay the other I'm seeing the form's backcolor come through as opposed to the underlaying image.

Am I missing a property that I can set?

Comment: Try it without the panels.  Simple stacking one panel on top another probably doesnt work because the parent of Panel2 is still the form (and therefore, the thing behind it), not the bottom panel.

Comment: The simplest way is to just use *one* PictureBox.  Either assign both BackgroundImage and Image or use its Paint event to draw the second image with e.Graphics.DrawImage()

Comment: The closest you can get while still using the PicturBox is to modify its Region() property so it is no longer rectangular in nature.

Answer (score 4):

You only need one picture box. The overlay can be done with graphics.

```
Imports System.Drawing

Dim OverlayImage As New Bitmap("Some Path", True)
Dim BackImage As New Bitmap("Some Path", True)
g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(BackImage)

g.DrawImage(OverlayImage, 0, 0)
pictureBox1.Image = BackImage
```

---

If you want to have the timer move the overlayed image, then first, make a variable
 `Dim posX As Integer = 0`
then use 
`g.DrawImage(OverlayImage, posX, 0)`
 Now when your timer ticks, increment `posX` by 10

Comment: There is some logic in why I have it set up in the current way: The location of the picture box inside the panel changes. I basically have a sprite in there so I change the picture box location in the panel to display a given frame. The panels then move around..

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. You want to be able to change the location of the picture that is being overlayed after the program starts, so you can't have locked-in coordinates.

Comment: I use a timer and each tick adds 10 to the x value of the position of the picturebox.

Comment: @Blue0500's answer is the correct way of doing this.  WinForms controls are not transparent, but they emulate transparency by copying the form image into themselves before drawing their content.

Comment: So you need to be able to move the overlayed picture with a timer?

Comment: Yes on a timer tick the image moves to the right by 10 (pixels I assume?). Anyhow at some point that image overlays another and I want to be able to see that image underneath as opposed to just the form background.

    What I think I'm going to do is have one big draw event and handle collision detection within the draw routine etc...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete function to overlay two images (adapted from Blue0500's answer):

```
''' <summary> Return a new image with one superimposed over the other. </summary>
Function OverlayImgs(ByVal BackgroundImg As System.Drawing.Bitmap, ByVal OverlayImg As System.Drawing.Bitmap, Position As System.Drawing.Point) As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Dim g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(BackgroundImg)
    g.DrawImage(OverlayImg, Position)
    Return BackgroundImg
End Function
```

Usage:

```
lblTest.Image = OverlayImgs(Img1, Img2, New Point(16, 16))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `PictureBox` for this unless you are using it for the canvas. You can draw all images to a Rectangle structure and move them around. Personally I would create a class object that has a Rectangle, Image and other properties and hold them in a collection. Then you simply draw the class objects by there properties including location. If there images contain transparencies they will overlay for you. This also gives you a method to check for collisions via the `Rectangle.IntersectsWith` function.

Comment: Okay, I'm guessing I'm going to have to re-think how I'm running this application...