# VB transparent picturebox over several pictureboxes

Tags: vb.net, forms, picturebox, transparent

I am currently writing a program that requires a picture box with a transparent image to go over several pictureboxes. I have looked for hours now and found nothing useful. the program is a rubiks cube solver. each square is represented as a picturebox and the cube is shown in a net form. I cant upload images as my account is new but i have included an image of a rubiks cube in a net form. now imagine a semi transparent image going over some of the squares (pictureboxes) to represent a visual guide to the rotation about to be made in the solve process. If you need more info I will do my best and upload images and add code for better clarification if needed. If this is not possible is there any alternatives that I could attempt? Thankyou

Comment: each picturebox is a member of form.Controls, so "behind" each picbox is the form, even if they are on top of each other.  you could try using the form's background image to display the "base" cube.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you want is possible. I was actually trying to solve the same problem about 2 days ago and to no avail. You can't have transparency to work with multiple pictureboxes on winforms. What you need to do is draw the images using `Graphics` like one over the other. Use 1 picturebox and do `Graphics` to overlay the picture on the picturebox. Or have the main picture as the form's background image and use pictureboxes, this was what I did. This is surely easier using WPF. Alternatively... Try to check this imaging SDK.

http://www.gdpicture.com/

This might help overlaying your images.

And this too, this is basically the one using 1 picturebox and overlaying using `Graphics`.

[VB.NET Winforms: Overlay two transparent images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180200/vb-net-winforms-overlay-two-transparent-images)

Comment: Thankyou for the usefull ideas. I will apply them and post back. I must have missed that thread when i was looking, Thankyou

Comment: I attempted to apply your ideas and writing to the form is the only one that would work. I have found an alternative which involves no overlaying images by simply creating an indicator away from the other pictureboxes and seeing as it is a school project I will leave it out. Thankyou