# VB.NET Winforms: Overlay two images and move overlay with timer

Tags: vb.net, image, winforms, animation, move

I would like to overlay 2 images and then move the top layer using a timer.

this is the code i'm trying to implement from this anwser: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180200/vb-net-winforms-overlay-two-transparent-images)

```
Imports System.Drawing

Dim OverlayImage As New Bitmap("Some Path", True)
Dim BackImage As New Bitmap("Some Path", True)
g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(BackImage)

g.DrawImage(OverlayImage, 0, 0)
pictureBox1.Image = BackImage
```

If you want to have the timer move the overlayed image, then first, make a variable

`Dim posX As Integer = 0`

then use

`g.DrawImage(OverlayImage, posX, 0)`

Now when your timer ticks, increment `posX` by 10

This is what i got but the overlay isn't moving.
What am i doing wrong? Can anybody help me?

```
Imports System.Drawing

Public Class Form1

    Dim OverlayImage As New Bitmap("D:/white.png", True)
    Dim BackImage As New Bitmap("D:/bg.png", True)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(BackImage)
    Dim posX As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Picturebox1.Image = BackImage

    End Sub



    Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint

        g.DrawImage(OverlayImage, posX, 0)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        posX = +10

    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: In your Timer1_Tick event, shouldn't you be doing something like actually moving the image?  Not sure about your usage of Graphics either, 1st off, will just draw a new version the image direct on the canvas on each iteration at a new location (ie Copy, not move) and Graphics implements IDisposable, which to me always means it should be declared, used and disposed of as needed.  You shouldn't really be using the one instance for the lifetime of your form less you get into memory leak issues

Comment: @Hursey could you maybe give me an example code?

Comment: There are plenty of good examples and documentation (and better than anything I can give you) of using graphics around, perhaps start with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/getting-started-with-graphics-programming?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8 .  As for the comment regarding the tick event, I couldn't even guess what example code you're expecting,