# Overlaying a transparent gif over picture box vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to develop a simple campus directory, I am using a 2D map of the campus, and I want to overlay a gif as the path I wonder if that's possible? I haven't started yet because I don't know what to do first.

I am expecting the gif to appear on top of an image if that's possible.

Comment: The answers here might give you a start.  (Tip: it's always a good idea to do some searching first, when you're just at square one)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180200/vb-net-winforms-overlay-two-transparent-images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with a function like this:-

```
    Public Function MergeImages(ByVal mainImage As Bitmap, ByVal secondaryImage As Bitmap, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal width As Integer, ByVal height As Integer) As Bitmap

        Dim mergedBmp As New Bitmap(mainImage.Width, mainImage.Height)

        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(mergedBmp)
            g.DrawImage(mainImage, 0, 0, mainImage.Width, mainImage.Height)
            g.DrawImage(secondaryImage, New Rectangle(x, y, width, height))
        End Using

        Return mergedBmp
    End Function
```

Using these two images:-

[image]
[image]

We can combine and get this:-
[image]

This is the code I used to do it:-

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim b1 As Bitmap = Bitmap.FromFile("d:\meadow.jpg")
        Dim b2 As Bitmap = Bitmap.FromFile("d:\stamps.png")

        Me.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch

        Dim smallWidth As Integer = 400
        Dim smallHeight As Integer = 400
        Dim centerX As Integer = (b1.Width \ 2) - (smallWidth \ 2)
        Dim centerY As Integer = (b1.Height \ 2) - (smallHeight \ 2)

        Me.BackgroundImage = MergeImages(b1, b2, centerX, centerY, 400, 400)

    End Sub
```

This should more than get you started.